# Struct delcaration calls for a wrong constructor

Tags: c++

This is my first time using struct. I need to initialize secure::secure() inside of main, but don't know what should I put there. It expects a default constructor which would skip all the declarations I made.

What should I do?

Also, there might be something else wrong with my code, I'd not be surprised. For now, please explain me only how do I refer to a specific declaration rather than a default one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct secure
{
    string surname;
    string name;
    string age;
    string placeofbirth;
    string tel;
    secure(const string& s, const string& n, string a, const string& p, const string& t);
};

secure::secure(const string& s, const string& n, string a, const string& p, const string& t)
:surname{s},
name{n},
age{a},
placeofbirth{p},
tel{t}
{
    if(!(find_if(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), [](const char z) {return !isalpha(z) && z != '-';}) == s.cend()))
        cout<<"You may not use characters that are not letters nor -."<<endl;
    if(!(find_if(n.cbegin(), n.cend(), [](const char x) {return !isalpha(x);}) == n.cend()))
        cout<<"You are allowed to only use letters."<<endl;
    if(a.find_first_not_of("0123456789"))
        cout<<"Age must be a positive integer."<<endl;
    if((find_if(p.cbegin(), p.cend(), [](const char c) {return !isspace(c);}) == p.cend()))
        cout<<"Spaces are not allowed."<<endl;
    if(t.find_first_not_of("1234567890+-"))
        cout<<"Telephone numbers consists only of digits, + and -."<<endl;
}

void perfection(struct secure &secure)
{
    quest:
    ofstream creation;
    ifstream created;

    cout<<"How many students' info will be entered?: ";
    string uservoice;
    getline(cin, uservoice);

    double enterholder;
    int sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int intage;

    if(!uservoice.find_first_not_of("1234567890-"))
    {
        cout<<"You shall enter an integer."<<endl;
        goto quest;
    }
        int replacement = 0;
        replacement=stoi(uservoice);

    creation.open("knight.txt");
    if(replacement>0)
    {
        enterholder = replacement;
        cout<<"Enter data "<<uservoice<<" times."<<endl;
        do
        {
            cout<<"Enter data as follows: "<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter surname: ";
            getline(cin, secure.surname);
            cout<<"Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, secure.name);
            cout<<"Enter age: ";
            getline(cin, secure.age);
            intage = stoi(secure.age);
            cout<<"Enter place of birth: ";
            getline(cin, secure.placeofbirth);
            cout<<"Enter telephone number: ";
            getline(cin, secure.tel);
            creation << secure.surname << '\t' << secure.name << '\t' << intage << '\t' << secure.placeofbirth << '\t' << secure.tel <<endl;
            replacement--;
        }while(replacement != 0);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"You shall enter a number bigger than 0."<<endl;
        goto quest;
    }
    creation.close();

    bool ensuretodisplay;
    stringstream hasstuff;
    stringstream abegins;

    string s, n, p, t;
    int a;

    created.open("knight.txt");
    while(created >> s >> n >> a >> p >> t)
    {
        ensuretodisplay = true;
        cout << s << '\t' << n << '\t' << a << '\t' << p << '\t' << t <<endl;
        hasstuff << s << t << endl;
        sum+=a;
        average = sum / enterholder;
        if(s.find("A") == 0)
        {
            abegins << s << n << endl;
        }
    }
    if(ensuretodisplay)
    {
        cout<<"Surnames and telephone numbers of all the students:\n"<<hasstuff.str()<<endl;
        cout<<"An average age of all the students is: "<< average<<endl;
        cout<<"Surnames and names of those whose surname begins with A:\n"<<abegins.str();
    }
    created.close();
}
int main()
{
    struct secure &exotic;
    perfection(exotic);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *but don't know what should I put there* -- When you create a constructor with those arguments without a default constructor, you've made a contract stating "this object is constructed this way".   So no one really can tell you "what to put there" -- it's your design, you make the decision.

Comment: The question is how do I tell main I will refer to struct in void by the statements in secure::secure(). It is my design to which I don't know how to refer to.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need to specify `struct` or `class` when declaring variables.

Comment: How do you tell the caller of your program that creation of `secure` failed?  (Hint:  exceptions).

Comment: Nice `goto`, have you tried replacing it with a `while` or `do-while` loop?

Comment: A good coding guideline is to give structures, classes and variables different names (especially differing by more than just case).  This guideline helps readers of your code differentiate between variables and types.

Comment: @GieniuszKrab -- You are mistaken, or you took `secure x;` for granted and believed all you were doing was declaring a variable called `x`.  No -- not only is a variable declared, the object is being *created*.   You are violating your own contract that an object must be created with 5 string arguments when you also say it can be created with no arguments.  There are two ways to not violate *your* contract -- one is to provide a default constructor (and again, **you** decide what it means to have a default object), or simply not call `secure()` and use it in your program.  It's your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a constructor that expects 5 input arguments (and you are not using it anywhere in your code). When you create an instance of the struct in `main()`, it tries to call a constructor with no arguments, and fails, because if you don't have a default constructor, you are telling it must be created your way. Just create another constructor without parameters and it should work.

```
struct secure
{
    string surname;
    string name;
    string age;
    string placeofbirth;
    string tel;
    secure(const string& s, const string& n, string a, const string& p, const string& t);
    secure(); //Defaul constr with no args
};

secure::secure()
{ 
    //you can do something here if you want
}
```

If you want to use your 5 arg. constructor, you have to declare it like this:

```
secure exotic(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);
```

Comment: How does it come I don't use it while stating getline(cin, secure.surname) and so on in void?

Comment: The constructor is only called when you create an object. In your void function, you are directly accessing and overwriting the member variables of your struct.

Comment: Makes sense. Does that mean I should create different strings in void so that I may apply stuff to them by the rules that were declared?

Comment: If you want to stick with your own constructor, then yes, but there are several ways to do it. Just google "c++ classes" if you want to learn more